# ZeroBrane - how to clear debug window?

Tags: lua, marmalade, zerobrane

I wonder if there is a way to clear the "local console" pane in ZeroBrane. Sometimes it gets "clogged" with no way to clean it - for example checking `_G` produces massive amount of text and everything slows to halt afterwards.

I am using v0.50 that came bundled with Marmalade, if that matters. I tried local menu (right-click) but there is nothing.

Comment: See my answer. I'll add clearing the console to the right-click menu in the next version; thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I've added clearing the console to the right-click menu and it will be included in the next version (1.21+).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clear` command (simply type `clear` and `Enter`), which will clear the console content (it's described in the introductory text at the top of the console window).

I suggest you upgrade to a newer version as 0.50 is quite old.

Comment: oh! thank you, i haven't noticed that text - now i read it and learnt about `=` as well.